# Finding out the DateTimeFormat obtained when DateTime.ToString( ) is called

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have the following issue with handling datetime formats for a component I am developing.

```
string value = DateTime.Now.ToString( ); // value = "8/3/2010 2:20:49 PM"
```

How do I find out which date format `value` refers to --> `"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"`

I wish to store this current datetime format during export and use the same during import. Various apis available in `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` and `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat` do not provide this info.

One solution I know of is to use dt.ToString( "u" ) to store and parse datetime in universal format, but I am curious how I could get the above format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation:

```
DateTime.ToString()
```

> The value of this instance is formatted using the general format specifier, 'G', as described in the Formatting Overview topic. The return value is identical to the value returned by `ToString ("G", null)`.

Following the doc links Formatting Overview -> Date And Time Format Strings -> Standard DateTime Format Strings gets us to

> G
>
> General date/time pattern (long time)
>
> Displays a combination of the short date and long time patterns, separated by a space.

So the format you want should be obtainable by combining the `ShortDatePattern` and `LongTimePattern` members of `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want reliable import / export of DateTimes, it is best to set the used format specified explicitly, e.g. using the invariant culture.

Comment: yeah. I am using that, but wanted to know if I could obtain the current datetime format.

Comment: See Kangkan's answer. The LongDatePattern and LongTimePattern properties of the current culture will provide you with this information.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern` for the current datetime format.